# Convert arrays of strings to one array JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I faced a problem with array convertions.
I have an array with different values like:

```
let fruitsArry = ['apple', 'apple, mango, orange', 'orange'];
```

And I need to convert it to array like:

```
let fruitsArrSplited = ['apple', 'apple', 'mango', 'orange', 'orange'];
```

Could you suggest me any simple solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please remove `reactjs` flag

Answer (score 4):

Just join and split with the separator of the quoted part.

```js
let fruitsArray = ['apple', 'apple, mango, orange', 'orange'],
    result = fruitsArray.join(', ').split(', ');
    
console.log(result);
```

With white space after comma, you could split with optional whitepsace.

```js
let fruitsArray = ['apple', 'apple, mango, orange', 'orange'],
    result = fruitsArray.join().split(/,\s*/);
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: ahhh beautiful!

Comment: @Isaac what if the array do not have whitespaces between commas?

Answer (score 4):

Just use `join(',')` and `split(',')`. And further use `map()` (optional) to remove the trailing and leading whitespaces. This will also ensures that there can be any amount of whitespaces between array element.

```js
let fruitsArry = ['apple', 'apple, mango, orange', 'orange'];
var res = fruitsArry.join(',').split(',').map(item=>item.trim());
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Without `join(" ,")` which generates an unnecessary intermediate string, you may do as follows;

```js
var fruitsArry = ['apple', 'apple, mango, orange', 'orange'],
    result     = fruitsArry.reduce((r,e) => r.concat(e.includes(",") ? e.split(/\s*,\s*/)
                                                                     : e),[]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let array = ['apple', ' apple , mango , orange ', 'orange'];

newArray = array.join(',').split(/\s*,\s*/);
    
console.log(newArray);
```

I think this should do the trick. This will handle white space before and after each word too.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question simply you can use:

```
const af=a=>a.join(',').split(',').map(e=>e.trim()); // 45 character
```

and use it like:

```
let res = af(['apple', 'apple, mango, orange', 'orange']);
console.log(res);
```

Or if you prefer the long version:

```
/**
 * Define the function
 */
function formatArray(arr) {
  let tmp: string[];
  let result: string[] = [];

  tmp = arr.join(',').split(',');

  tmp.forEach((el, i) => {
    let str = el.trim();  // this is to remove the extra spaces
    result.push(str); // add the element to final array
  });
  return result;
}
```

And use it as:

```
// The orignal array
let arr = ['apple', 'apple, mango, orange', 'orange'];
arr = formatArray(arr);
console.log(arr);
```

Note that trimming part in the function, is an option you might not need this in your case but I figured out this is what you might want.

Answer (score 0):

You may use _js. [Underscore Js Documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#chain)

```
let fruitsArry = ['apple', 'apple, mango, orange', 'orange'];
var res = _.chain(fruitsArry).map(function(fruit) { return fruit.split(',') }).flatten().value()

console.log(res)
```

Comment: No need to use a whole library just for a simple function like that.

Comment: Yes, But it might be an optional, if you need to perform some complex operations. At that time it might help. Stating that you may use other way around too.

Comment: If OP already has underscore or lodash in his project, that's cool. But the solution in plain javascript is simple without it too.

Comment: yes, you are right. But in the future, some one might use it. Just making sure that the other possibilities are their to do it with the help of libraries.